# How to unblock with mysqladmin flush hosts

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have gone through similar cases listed here but it doesn't seem to work.

I was using MySQL Workbench to establish a connection with my database which is hosted on another server. Tried a few times and unable to connect followed by this error. I am confused as to where I should even do this flush. On PhpMyadmin under the SQL query? Cos when I tried to input the following command, it returns as syntax error. I am using a windows OS thus no shell scripting for me to input this information either. I am accessing the database temporarily via Cpanel/ phpmyadmin now.

Please help to tell where I should input this data and if my syntax is wrong. Thanks for help.

```
mysqladmin flush-hosts;

or

mysqladmin -umyname -pmypassword flush-hosts;
```

My error message as follows:

> Failed to connect to MYSql at 192.*.*.* with user myName
>
> Host 'host-92.*.*.*.as13285.net' is blocked because of many connection
> errors; unblock with  'mysqladmin flush-hosts'

Comment: You didn't specify what actual error you're getting...

Comment: Hi I have edited and added in my error message. Tnks.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

`mysqladmin` is not a SQL statement. It's a little helper utility program you'll find on your MySQL server... and "flush-hosts" is one of the things it can do.  ("status" and "shutdown" are a couple of other things that come to mind).

You type that command from a shell prompt.

Alternately, from your query browser (such as phpMyAdmin), the SQL statement you're looking for is simply this:

```
FLUSH HOSTS;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/flush.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqladmin.html

Comment: The weird thing with FLUSH is: how can you send that to the server if any connection is blocked? You'd need a separate host from which you can send FLUSH HOSTS.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but when you run `mysqladmin` or use the `mysql` command line client from the server itself, it won't see you coming in from your workstation, it will see you coming in from "localhost" or 127.0.0.1 or one of the server's Ethernet IP addresses, depending on how you call it, with `--host ip.add.re.ss` or typically "localhost" if you don't specify, at least on unix.

Comment: The MySQL server actually does not have max_connections, but an extra one for just such situations.  See [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html) for details.

Comment: Please see the following note from [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flush.html)  

FLUSH HOSTS is deprecated as of MySQL 8.0.23; expect it to be removed in a future MySQL release. Instead, truncate the Performance Schema host_cache table:  
  
`TRUNCATE TABLE performance_schema.host_cache;`  

The TRUNCATE TABLE operation requires the DROP privilege for the table rather than the RELOAD privilege.

Answer (score 44):

You should put it into command line in windows.

```
mysqladmin -u [username] -p flush-hosts
**** [MySQL password]
```

or

```
mysqladmin flush-hosts -u [username] -p
**** [MySQL password]
```

For network login use the following command:

```
mysqladmin -h <RDS ENDPOINT URL> -P <PORT> -u <USER> -p flush-hosts
mysqladmin -h [YOUR RDS END POINT URL] -P 3306 -u [DB USER] -p flush-hosts
```

you can permanently solution your problem by editing my.ini file[Mysql configuration file]
change variables max_connections = 10000;

or

login into MySQL using command line -

```
mysql -u [username] -p
**** [MySQL password]
```

put the below command into MySQL window

```
SET GLOBAL max_connect_errors=10000;
set global max_connections = 200;
```

check veritable using command-

```
show variables like "max_connections";
show variables like "max_connect_errors";
```

Comment: This works for me but: I have a task that runs monthly and the only one that uses mysql. Every time it errors out because of this and I have to go and increase the max connections and errors values. How do I set it permanently without having to reset it every month?

Comment: Hi, I am looking to fix it permanently. So, which one I need to increase the count, whether `max_connect_errors` or `max_connections` ?

Answer (score 4):

You can easily restart your MySql service. This kicks the error off.

Comment: Restarting a service for any reason other then a crash is unacceptable. I would even say that not even configuration changes should need a restart. a reload at most (very different)

Comment: it may be not recommended to do, but it's still an option though, so thanks for sharing

Comment: And it also purges  cache, installs pending patches etc, so be careful