# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, centos7

I've tried looking for the answer but nothing helped. There's a script running on php with pdo and it refuses to work. In fact any script that works with pdo connecting to a mysql server refuses to work on the server.

The thing is that it works fine on the other VPS and what even more weird is that it worked perfectly until 2 days ago. Then it just stopped working, even though I didn't change anything. So I reinstalled VPS several times and nothing helped. I've gotten a new VPS and situation is the same.

Server uses Centos 7 64x, Nginx, Mariadb, Php-fpm, php-mysq and php-pdo.

That thing happened before and last time I fixed it by reinstalling VPS a couple of times but now it just doesn't seem to work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

May be I'm missing something obvious, I don't know, I hope you can help.

Full error code:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   '92.***.*.***' (13)' in /usr/share/nginx/html/checkercs.php:32 Stack
>   trace: #0 /usr/share/nginx/html/checkercs.php(32):
>   PDO->__construct('mysql:host=92.....', '*****', '*********...') #1
>   {main} thrown in /usr/share/nginx/html/checkercs.php on line 32

Line 32:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_DB, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
```

As I said before, script is fine, it works on the other server. It's the server that is trouble.

Comment: Just be sure 1) mariadb is running 2) the IP is correct 3) the login info is correct 4) the user's privileges are correct  (check your privileges/rights) ... If that doesn't help, try searching for more answers ....... (BTW localhost may not be the same as 127.0.0.1 in privileges, be sure to add both!)...

Comment: Turned out it was in fact a server problem. This solved it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285318/how-to-unblock-with-mysqladmin-flush-hosts