# MySQL Host is blocked because of many connection errors

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, database-connection, ubuntu-14.04

we currently have a major issue on our production server. We have a MySQL DB on one server (Ubuntu 14.04 and MySQL version 5.5.57).

We have another server with all the applications talking to the database on server one. For 5 days now we keep getting this error on the second server:

```
05-09-2017 00:00:01 WARN com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@623841b8 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor32.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1015)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2395)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2316)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor19.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:347)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:146)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:195)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:184)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:200)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1086)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1073)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:648)
  Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Host 'IP_ADDRESS' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'"
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1114)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2493)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2334)
```

We have been trying for 5 days to resolve this, but every time we restart mysql its a couple of hours then the error starts again. I have upped the max_connect_errors from 10 to 50, but that just prolonged the error.

Then we have also adjusted the log level to 2, but the only thing we ever see in the error log is aborted connections, no 'denied' connections.

Is there any way I can see the actual connection errors? Please help to resolve this, I do not know how to resolve. We also don't have a DBA, so its just a dev team who are not database experts.

EDIT: The application is a Java maven application, using hibernate to connect to the database. Here is the hibernate config file:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">USERNAME_HERE</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">PASSWORD_HERE</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://SERVER_HERE:3306/voda_soccer?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.autoReconnect">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property> 

    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>

    <mapping class="com.myapp.sms.producer.entity.Customer"></mapping>
    <mapping class="com.myapp.sms.producer.entity.Gifting"></mapping>
    <mapping class="com.myapp.sms.producer.entity.BulkCampaign"></mapping>
</session-factory>
```

We always close connections in a finally block:

```
} finally {
        if (session != null) {
            try {
                session.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
        session = null;
    }
```

I know we can flush the hosts or restart MySQL, but I cannot do this all the time in production server. I want to find out WHY we are getting the connection errors and where to see them?

Comment: Are you closing your connections?

Comment: Are you sharing your Connection object between multiple threads, these objects aren't thread safe

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285318/how-to-unblock-with-mysqladmin-flush-hosts

Comment: We are using hibernate to handle the connections for us and its in a Maven Java project. I have added the hibernate config file

Comment: You still need to close your connections - even if they error - check your code.

Comment: We always close connections in a finally block - have added that as well

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/32972

Comment: To solve connection error, you will have to set a higher value for the variables max_connect_errors and max_connections value in your my.ini file (MySQL configuration file). If max_connect_errors failed 10 requests, then mysql assumes that there is some issue and blocks the host. You can try executing flush-hosts, then set the above variables in my.ini file and restart MySQL. I use [Monyog](https://www.webyog.com/product/monyog) to keep a track of my MySQL server (even I am a beginner at MySQL), and it helped me in monitoring my server variables, you can also give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is a connection leak or you might have long running queries that prevent other code segments to acquire a connection.

Depending on the datasource tool (c3p0,hikari etc) that you use, you can monitor your pool through jmx (jsconsole,visual vm).

Also you can use [Flexy Pool](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/flexy-pool) to do some monitoring.

Mysql workbench also provides some useful tools in order to get more info on the action that is responsible.