# MySQL with Qt issue

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

Can high `Aborted_clients` value lead to Host `IP` is blocked because of many connection errors? I want to known it because such error blocks my `Qt` application from accessing the database server.

**Error message:**

> QSqlDatabasePrivate::database: unable to open database: "Host 'IP' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts' QMYSQL: Unable to connect"

Also, can `Aborted_clients` value increase the `max_connect_errors` value?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are Globally unrelated. `max_connect_errors` is one of [Server System Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html) , it is a **per host** basis counter while `Aborted_clients` is one of the [Server status variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-status-variables.html) which is a global information counter for all clients/hosts.

Another reason they are not related, when the **host** whose `max_connect_errors` counter is in an incrementing cycle due to connect errors but then that host establishes a successful connection, the error count `max_connect_errors` for the host is *cleared*!

`max_connect_errors` is incremented *for a particular host* when the host fails to establish and **no successful connection** (threshold results in blocking the host). It happens when the handshake with the server was interrupted.  If it wasn’t interrupted, it counts as “success” and reset the host counter – regardless of whether the end result was a successful connection or not. so it can be considered as a network performance counter, Note that it does not even strongly stand for security issues. You can test this by `telnet MyServer 3306` then pressing `CTRL C` instead of proceeding ..

This counter could be cleared with `mysqladmin flush-hosts;` as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285318/how-to-unblock-with-mysqladmin-flush-hosts).

On the other hand, if a **client successfully connects** , but later disconnects improperly or is terminated, the server increments the `Aborted_clients` counter.

This can be caused by many things - The client exited without calling `mysql_close()`.  Client connection exceeded `wait_timeout` without interacting with server. The client connection wast cut off  like when turning off the PC.

**Server status variables**  provide *information* about Server operation, It also includes `Aborted_connects` which is just a statistic for DBAs- not used by mysqld to determine server behavior.